# How to validate login using Slim PHP

Tags: angularjs, pdo, authentication, slim

I'm using AngularJS (Front end), Slim Framework (Back end), PHP and MySQL. I am trying to validate  both user email and password with the database stored values but I am able to login with incorrect email and password. I can't see where is my problem. Please help me! Here is my code

login.html

```
<form novalidate name="SigninForm" id="add-new-form" method="post" action=""> <div class="form-group">
  <label for="first_name">Email:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="user.email" required />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="address">Password:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="user.password" />
</div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="SigninForm .$invalid || isUnchanged(user)" id="login" ng-click="signin(user)">Login!</button></form>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('CrudApp', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) 
{
  $routeProvider.
when('/', {templateUrl: 'assets/tpl/home.html', controller: HomeCtrl}).
 when('/login-user', {templateUrl: 'assets/tpl/login.html', controller: LoginCtrl}).
otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
function HomeCtrl($scope, $http) 
{
  $http.get('api/users').success(function(data) 
  {
    $scope.users = data;
  });
}
function LoginCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
  $scope.master = {};
  $scope.activePath = null;
  $scope.signin = function(user, AddNewForm) {
    $http.post('api/login_user', user).success(function(){
      $scope.reset();
      $scope.activePath = $location.path('/list-user');
      //alert('No access available.');
    });
    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };
    $scope.reset();
  };
}
```

index.php

```
<?php

require 'Slim/Slim.php';

$app = new Slim();

$app->post('/login_user', 'login');

$app->run();


function login()                                                    
{
    $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $user = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $email= $user->email;
    $password= $user->password;

if(!empty($email)&&!empty($password))
    {
        $sql="SELECT name, email FROM user WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
        $db = getConnection();
    try {
        $result=$db->query($sql); 

                if (!$result) { // add this check.
                      die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                }
        $row["user"]= $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db=null;
        echo json_encode($row);

    } catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/tmp/php.log');
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
    }
}

function getConnection() {
    $dbhost="127.0.0.1";
    $dbuser="root";
    $dbpass="";
    $dbname="TQA";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}

?>
```

Comment: Hey! Have the answer below ever helped you? If so, please accept it. It may help others seeking a solution for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're returning a successful result regardless the user input. Apache, nginx, and PHP's built-in web server return a default HTTP code 200 for requests that they could handle without problems. Since your route doesn't explicitly fails, it seems for your server everything is OK with request/response.

You should, for instance, return a response with code 400 (**Bad request**) if the user submits the form with email or password empty. Also, you might return a code 401 (**Unauthorized**) if no user matching the given email and password was found in the database.

You may refer to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html on more information about HTTP status codes.

When using the proper status codes, the `login` function may look something like this:

```php
function login()
{
    $app = Slim::getInstance();
    $request = $app->request();
    $user = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $email = $user->email;
    $password = $user->password;
    if (empty($email) || empty($password)) {
        $error = 'Email and password are required';

        // Bad request
        return jsonResponse($error, 400);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT name, email FROM user "
        . "WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
    $db = getConnection();
    $row = array();
    try {
        $result = $db->query($sql); 
        if (!$result) {
            $error = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error();

            // Internal server error
            return jsonResponse($error, 500);
        }
        $user = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if (empty($user)) {

            // Unauthorized
            return jsonResponse($error, 401);
        }
        $row["user"] = $user;
        $db = null;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/tmp/php.log');
        $error = array( 'error' => array ( 'text' => $e->getMessage() ) );

        // Internal server error
        return jsonResponse($error, 500);
    }

    // OK, default is 200
    return jsonResponse($row);
}
```

In the code above I'm using the following function to avoid code repetition. It's not part of Slim or PHP, so if you want to use it, add it to your project.

```php
function jsonResponse($data, $code = 200)
{
    $app = Slim::getInstance();
    $app->response->setStatus($code);
    $app->response->headers->set(
        'Content-type',
        'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    );
    return $app->response->setBody(json_encode($data));
}
```